# how does windows remote access works without internet?

Tags: windows

*which technology they use for the backend in windows for remote access without internet?*

**here is the link -**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-remote-desktop-5fe128d5-8fb1-7a23-3b8a-41e636865e8c#connect-using-remote-desktop-connection=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

In fact when you are not connect to internet you can not Access to other devices by remote access tools.in this case you can access to devices which are in your Local network only.
another condition is your device does not connect to internet directly but nearest your local router which has NAT configuration connected to internet and you use this router IP as gateway.so you are connected to internet and can remote access to other devices in your VLAN.

Answer (score 0):

This may be my misunderstanding but you require a network connection to connect to Microsoft remote desktop..

No network connection no remote desktop.

Remote desktop works bt connecting across the network/Internet to TCP PORT 3389.

Now you "could" connect via modem but it would be so SLOOOOOWWWWW as to be basically unusable.

It is discussed here https://superuser.com/questions/992183/connect-2-pcs-together-via-the-pstn-using-dial-up-modems

Good luck

Tom